# Send data to the backend API Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angular6

i'm trying to send few form details to the backend API using angular6, but it doesn't work as i expected, and how do i add Observable to this, im expecting to use observable instead of promises.

**login.component.html**

```
loginUser(e){

    var username = e.target.elements[0].value;
    var password = e.target.elements[1].value;
    console.log(username,password);

      this.user.setUserLoggedIn()
      var body = "username=" + username + "password=" + password;
      this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/user/all", body).subscribe((data) => {});
       this.router.navigate(['fullpage'])

    return false;
  }
```

**login.component.html**

```
<form id="loginForm" novalidate="novalidate" (submit)="loginUser($event)">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="" required="" title="Please enter you username" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value="" required="" title="Please enter your password" placeholder="******">
                                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="loginErrorMsg" class="alert alert-error hide">Wrong username or password</div>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>

                                </form>
```

**Error:**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LogincomponentComponent -> Http]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LogincomponentComponent -> Http]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Http! Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LogincomponentComponent -> Http]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LogincomponentComponent -> Http]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to Add `http` module into your `app.module` like this -

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [HttpModule]
...
```

PS:

- If you are using `HttpClientModule` make changes accordingly
- `HttpModule` is deprecated in v>5

Comment: now i'm getting 

`ERROR Response {_body: "{"timestamp":1529392191129,"status":415,"error":"U…harset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/user/save"}", status: 415, ok: false, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}`

Comment: This error is coming from backend server

Comment: HttpModule is deprecated in angular6, don't recommend usage of deprecated modules

Comment: @bambam Can you please let me know where in the question mentioned that OP is using `httpClient` ? also I am mentioned in my answer about `httpClientModule` as well

Comment: and FYI `httpModule` is still in working state for some versions , so why DOWNVOTE??

Comment: @bambam Strange behaviour of peoples like you, Surprise have you really read my answer before downvoting. anyways OP accepted my answer so must be know now my answer is perfact for person who ask this

Comment: Bro never mind, 
I already statated about new module , if you still think my answer can be improved you can edit it. I would be more than happy :)

Comment: Strange, WHy I am still getting downotes?

Comment: @bambam Now why have you deleted all your comments from here??

Answer (score 0):

You should import `HttpModule` or `HttpClientModule` in app.module file
and add it to imports array

If your http object is of type Http import `HttpModule` 
If your http object is of type HttpClient import `HttpClientModule`

and body object is not of type string it is object type
it should be

```
body = { username, password }
```

Comment: HttpModule is deprecated in angular6, don't recommend usage of deprecated modules

Comment: I added it to now i'm getting ERROR Response {_body: "{"timestamp":1529392191129,"status":415,"error":"U…harset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/user/save"}", status: 415, ok: false, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}

Comment: @bambam I did not recommend to use HttpModule just advised to import it if the already import http object is from HttpModule

Comment: @SibaBoba It is probably a Backend error

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score -1):

In order to use Http in your app you will need to add the HttpModule to your app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ]
```

Comment: HttpModule is deprecated in angular6, don't recommend usage of deprecated modules

Comment: now i'm getting ERROR Response {_body: "{"timestamp":1529392191129,"status":415,"error":"U…harset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/user/save"}", status: 415, ok: false, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}